# PromQL: time from last value of a series

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have multiple server instances that are exporting various metrics. Frequently, some instances are offline, therefore, they don't export anything.

I would like to create a panel that would simply display a table in which each server instance is represented by a row and states how long (hh:mm) the server has been offline (i.e. a duration between last exported datapoint in a series and now).

Example output:

```
instance  | offline_duration
----------------------------
instance1 | 00:00
instance2 | 01:12
instance3 | 25:10
```

I have multiple other use-cases in which I would appreciate both the ability of selecting the last value (of all times) and measuring time duration from now to the series data point.

Semantically, I was hoping for something like `now() - timestamp(last_over_time(my_metric))` but this has a lot of obvious problems such as `last_over_time` requires a range-vector.

Is this even possible? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be possible with subquery:

```
time() - (
  max_over_time(
     ( timestamp(your_metric) )[2h:1m]
  )
)
```

`2h` here is the time window - how far into the past query should look for last data point

Comment: Thanks! It almost works. I had to 1) add `max( .... ) by (instance)` and 2) add Reduce transformation (Series to rows, Calculation `Last*`, Lbales to fields=off). All of this works with the table view as expected. Thanks a lot!